# Hide all div.class children of TD, then show first div.class child

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-table, css-cascade

The following should work in theory, to the best of my knowledge, but is not:

```css
td small.attachments {
  display: none;
}
td small.attachments:first-child {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="views-field-field-entry-images-fid">
      <a href="#"><img src="x.jpg" /></a>
      <small class="attachments">Files<div class="file-listing">Content A + B</div></small>
      <small class="attachments">Files<div class="file-listing">Content B</div></small>
      <small class="links">Links<div class="file-listing">Content C</div></small>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result is, any time a small.attachments element has no small.attachment siblings, it is shown fine, with the first-child rule applied and overriding the display:none rule.

However, when there are two small.attachments elements in a TD, one after the other (in example above), **BOTH** are hidden, and the first-child rule has no effect.

What's going on?

PS: I've tested in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Note you can't place `div` elements inside `small` ones. And you could try `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I've misunderstood the intention of the "first-child" property.

As an IE-compliant fix, I used jQuery to wrap the `<small>` elements in a `<div>` on a per `<td>` basis.

The rules then worked as expected and according to spec.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("td.views-field-field-entry-images-fid").each(function() {

    $(this).children("small").wrapAll("<div class='attachments-wrapper'></div>");

  });

</script>
```

Thanks for the refresher!

Comment: Heh, that's cheating by adding elements through JS :) I like it! Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say this, but "It Works For Me", see this JSBin example:

http://jsbin.com/ovuro4/ ( http://jsbin.com/ovuro4/edit )

Updated version: http://jsbin.com/ovuro4/3/edit based on your feedback below.

The result as I understand it from your post is that in this case is that "Files" -> "Content A + B" should be visible, while "Files" -> "Content B" should not be visible. That's how it shows up for me, in Safari and FF.

Comment: That does work, but that's not quite what my TD contents were. Try http://jsbin.com/utoni4/4

Comment: Then therein lies your answer. The `<a>` is the first-child, not the `<small>` you want, so the selector does not match :)

Comment: Then how do I target "the first SMALL element in each TD?" In my situation, I have to work without adding any other IDs or classes.

Comment: I would offer to use :first-of-type()... but as usual IE does not support that. http://jsbin.com/ovuro4/3/edit - you could use http://selectivizr.com/ to help.. but if adding new IDs or classes is a no-go (and I presume adding new DOM elements is completely out of the question?), this one might not fly either.

Comment: selectivizr.com will prove most handy for my future styling. Thank you!